# Mass flow of vapour produced while boiling water in an open system

Tags: thermodynamics

Suppose that I'm boiling water in an open pot. As the pot is heated by the stove, it loses mass to the surrounding in the form of water vapour.

The pot is my control volume. That system could be modeled by the following equations:

**Mass balance:**

$$
    \frac{d}{dt} (m_L + m_V) = 0
$$

$$
    \frac{dm_L}{dt} = -\frac{dm_V}{dt} = -\dot m_{out}
$$

Since the water vapour immediately leaves the pot (neglecting recondensation), the overall mass balance in the pot is

$$
    \frac{dm}{dt} = -\dot m_{out}
$$

**Energy balance:**
$$
    \frac{dU}{dt} = \dot H_{in} - \dot H_{out} + \dot Q + \dot W_s
$$

That is how the general equation for energy balances in open systems is usually written in Chemical Engineering. If you are unfamiliar with that equation, there are enthalpy flow rates in the right side of the equation, in lieu of internal energies, because we divide work in shaft work ($\dot W_s$) and flow work ($-\Delta p\dot V$), which combines with internal energy to make those enthalpies.

In the system we are modeling, $\dot H_{in} = \dot W_s = 0$.

The internal energy in the left side of the equation can be divided on liquid and vapour components:

$$
    U = m_L u_L + m_V u_V
$$

$$
    U = m_L u_L + (m_0 - m_L)\cdot (u_L + \Delta u_{vap})
$$
$$
    \frac{dU}{dt} = -\Delta u_{vap} \frac{dm_L}{dt}
$$

Let's say $T_b$ (boiling temperature) is given in celsius and my reference state for calculating enthalpy is liquid water at 0°C. Then the enthalpy of the vapour leaving the system is $-\dot m_{out} (c_p^{liq} T_b + \Delta h_{vap})$.

Hence,

$$
    -\Delta u_{vap} \frac{dm_L}{dt} = -\dot m_{out} (c_p^{liq} T_b + \Delta h_{vap}) + \dot Q
$$

Combining with the mass balance,

$$
    \dot m_{out} = \frac{\dot Q}{c_p^{liq}T_b+\Delta h_{vap}+\Delta u_{vap}}
$$

That result weirds me out and I am sure I've commited a mistake.

In the first place, that $h_{out} = c_p^{liq}T_b + \Delta h_{vap}$ is dependant on the reference state I choose for enthalpy, which was liquid water at 0°C in this case. But if I had chosen liquid water at $T_b$, it would be just $h_{out} = \Delta h_{vap}$. And if I had chosen water vapour at $T_b$, then $h_{out} = 0$. My mass flow cannot depend on the reference state I have chosen for calculating enthalpies.

In the second place, $\Delta h_{vap} + \Delta u_{vap}$ is a very weird term... I'd take $\Delta h_{vap}-\Delta u_{vap} = p \Delta v_{vap}$, but $\Delta h_{vap} + \Delta u_{vap} = 2\Delta u_{vap} + p\Delta v_{vap}$ and that does not look right... I'm sure I messed up my signs, but can't see where.

Attributing some numbers to the problem, just to see if the results at least seem plausible, $c_p^{liq} \approx 4.18$ kJ/kg°C, $\Delta h_{vap} \approx 2250$ kJ/kg and $\Delta u_{vap} \approx 2090$ kJ/kg at 1 atm. Let's say $\dot Q = 1.0$ kW.

Using the values above, $\dot m_{out} \approx 2\times10^{-4} kg/s $, or around 79 minutes to boil 1 kg of water.

I'd appreciate some reviews.

Comment: I'm not sure how you define your open system. If it is liquid water at time $t$, the vapor should not be taken into account in the internal energy of the open system?

Comment: Hmm... then the internal energy would be just $u_L m_L \approx  m_L c_v T_b $, and $\frac{dU}{dt} = c_v T_b \frac{dm_L}{dt}$? I think that could work. The terms dependant on the choice of a reference state would cancel out...

Comment: There are 2 deficiencies in your application of the open system version of the 1st law of thermodynamics to solving this problem. 1.  You did not recognize that the rate of vaporization of liquid water is not equal to the rate that water vapor exits the pot.  2.  Total neglect of the key condition that the volume of liquid water at any time plus the volume of water vapor must sum to the total pot volume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct application of the open-system version of the 1st law of thermodynamics is as follows:

**MASS BALANCE**
$$\frac{dm_L}{dt}=-\dot{r_e}$$
$$\frac{dm_V}{dt}=+r_e-\dot{m}_{out}$$where $\dot{r}_e$is the rate of evaporation of liquid water.

**ENERGY BALANCE**
$$\frac{dU}{dt}=-\dot{m}_{out}h_V-\dot{Q}$$where$$U=m_Lu_L+m_Vu_V$$and $h_V=u_V+Pv_V$ is the enthalpy per unit mass of the vapor.  So, $$\frac{dU}{dt}=-\dot{r_e}u_L+(r_e-\dot{m}_{out})u_V=-\dot{m}_{out}h_V-\dot{Q}$$In addition, the volume of liquid in the pot plus the volume of vapor in the pot must away add up to the (constant)total pot volume $V_P$:  $$m_Lv_L+m_Vv_V=V_P$$or $$\frac{dm_L}{dt}v_L+\frac{dm_V}{dt}v_V=-\dot{r_e}v_L+(r_e-\dot{m}_{out})v_V=0$$where $v_L$ is the specific volume of the liquid and $v_V$ is the specific volume of the vapor.
If we combine the above equations and solve for the vaporization rate, we obtain simply $$\dot{r}_e=-\frac{dm_L}{dt}=\frac{\dot{Q}}{\Delta h_{vaporization}}=\frac{Q}{h_V-h_L}$$with$$h_V=u_V+Pv_V$$and$$h_L=u_L+Pv_L$$
This rate of liquid water vaporization is exactly what we would expect.

In addition, $$\dot(m)_{out}=\left(1-\frac{v_L}{v_V}\right)\dot{r}_e$$

Comment: Do you not have any questions about this?

Comment: High, Chet! Thank you for your very detailed answer. Indeed, I had some difficulties understanding your answer at first, but after a second reading I completely get it.

It's interesting to notice that, $\frac{v_L}{v_V}$ is a very small number (around 6e-4 for saturated water at 100°C), hence $\dot m_{out} \approx \dot r_e$. 

Neglecting that term, the solution I proposed looks a lot like yours, except for my huge blunder when defining $\frac{dU}{dt} = -\Delta u_{vap}\frac{dm}{dt}$. But I like your reasoning, that is more general and would work much better than mine near the critical point

Comment: My having lots of experience with this kind of approach helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's good to see that you are interrogating your result for consistency. As you are correct to say, the result cannot depend on the reference state.  I have not gone through your entire calculation but I disagree with your equation
$$
    \frac{dU}{dt} = -\Delta u_{vap} \frac{dm_L}{dt}
$$
The water is at its boiling temperature and its internal energy should be $u_L$, so the correct equation is
$$
    \frac{dU}{dt} = -u_L \frac{dm_L}{dt}
$$
From the [NIST webbook](https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/fluid.cgi?P=1%20bar&TLow=20&THigh=200&TInc=20&Digits=5&ID=C7732185&Action=Load&Type=IsoBar&TUnit=C&PUnit=bar&DUnit=mol%2Fl&HUnit=kJ%2Fkg&WUnit=m%2Fs&VisUnit=uPa*s&STUnit=N%2Fm&RefState=DEF), which uses liquid water at 0°C as the reference sate, at 1 bar we find $u_L = 417.40$ kJ/kg. Similarly, the vapor leaves as saturated vapor, so $h_\text{out}=h_V = 2674.9$ kJ/kg (from the same NIST link). See if this fixes the problem.

Comment: I think it does fix my problem, thank you! Sadly I don't have enough reputation yet to upvote your answer.